# Trazer os registros de uma tabela de acordo com o where de outra

Tags: sql, query

Sou novato na área de banco de dados e me deparei com uma situação que não sei como solucionar. Mesmo parecendo (pelo menos parece, rs) simples.

Existe a tabela chamada `dbo.FISICA` e outra chamada `dbo.MATRICULA`, na tabela `dbo.FISICA` ficam todos os "clientes" do sistema, que possuam matrícula ou não, e na tabela `dbo.MATRICULA` ficam as matriculas destes clientes, cada cliente pode possuir uma ou mais matrículas, assim:

```
TABELA dbo.FISICA:

CODIGO  NOME     SEXO   DATANASC      CPF   
------  ----     ----   --------      ---
1       Otavio   M      22/05/1994    111.111.111-11
2       Luis     M      21/04/1993    222.222.222-22

TABELA dbo.MATRICULA:

CODIGO   FISICA   CURSO   STATUS
------   ------   -----   ------
1        1        3       0
2        1        4       2
3        1        5       4
4        2        3       0
```

A minha intenção é fazer uma query que traga os alunas que possuem apenas matrícula com status 0, então neste caso na minha query deveria trazer **apenas** o Luis.

Eis minha query:

```
select
F.NOME,
M.STATUS
from dbo.MATRICULA M
Left join dbo.FISICA F on F.CODIGO = M.FISICA
Left join dbo.TURMAS T on T.CODIGO = M.TURMA_REGULAR
WHERE M.STATUS = 0
```

E o resultado:

```
NOME    STATUS
----    ------
Otavio  0
Luis    0
```

Pois obviamente ele me trouxe os alunos que possuem matrícula status 0, e não **que só possuam matricula status 0**.

Comment: Qual provedor? Sql Server? Mysql? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é contar quantos status do cara são diferente de 0 e filtrar somente os que tem 0, veja:

```
SELECT F.nome, 
       M.status 
FROM   matricula M 
       JOIN fisica F 
         ON F.codigo = M.fisica 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   matricula 
        WHERE  fisica = F.codigo 
               AND status <> 0) = 0
```

Veja funcionando no [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9bac8/11/0).

Answer (score 1):

Adicione a clausula para retornar somente as matriculas que não existam matriculas com status diferente de 0

```
...
WHERE M.STATUS = 0
and not exists (select 1 from dbo.MATRICULA ma where ma.FISICA = M.FISICA and ma.STATUS <> 0)
```